# is there any advantage of using service methods as static instead of as instance methods

Tags: angularjs

Since angular creates only one instance of a service, I'm wondering whether maybe I should switch to using static methods. Is there any advantage to it?
This is how I use it now:

```
angular.service("mainService", function(){ this.move = function(){} });
```

Usage:

```
["mainService", function(mainService){ mainService.move() }]
```

This is how I can define and use it as static methods:

```
angular.factory("mainService", function() { return mainService; } );
function mainService() {};
mainService.move = function(){};
```

Usage is the same:

```
["mainService", function(mainService){ mainService.move() }]
```

Comment: Have you tried using the second snippet? What is injected by angular is the value **returned** by the mainService factory function. So `undefined` would be injected.

Comment: Yeah, changed the snippet

Comment: So, the service is now a function which does nothing, but has other attributes of type function. This is valid and works fine, but what's the point of returning a function that does nothing, rather than returning an object that would have the same attributes? If at least the returned function did something, it would start making sense. See for example the $http service, which can be called directly (`$http({url: '...', method: 'GET'})`), but also provides shortcut methods: `$http.get('...')`.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good example, thanks, I'll take a look at it